# How can a Data Factory see the result set of a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, resultset

I've only been at Data Factory for a short while and so far, looks OK. But I could hardly believe it when I found (apparently) that I *cannot* get at the result set of a SQL Server stored procedure. Is this really true? It looks like I might have to execute that stored procedure and get it to put the output into a (permanent!) table which I *can* read. Crazy?

Comment: Hi @JohnD - a common misconception for new ADF users is to approach it like SSIS. Data does not move from activity to activity. While you may not get the result in the Pipeline, you can access it in some activities and Data Flow.

Comment: You can just get at it via a Lookup if required.  What’s the use case?

Comment: As a workaround, I put the output of the SP in a table and used Lookup to read the table; in this use case, that was OK, as I could could clear the table just before populate, which would not work -so easily - in some other cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is by design, you **cannot view the actual output** of the stored procedure results, instead you just see the activity execution results.

You can add your points to support this similar idea already logged here [Logging support for Store Procedure Pipeline](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/0b7ac046-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

Comment: Crazy.. one more reason to run away from Azure and leave a big warning sign to anyone else coming.